# Wordpress BeTheme Error when trying to edit templates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, x-frame-options, cross-origin-read-blocking

I recently downloaded the BeTheme for WordPress and installed a prebuilt site. I can't seem edit edit templates though. It is preventing me from being able to edit the header and footer, and also preventing me from creating new templates. When I go to the templates page and click Edit with BeBuilder, it tries to open but fails with the following browser console error.

[image]

I've tried modifying htaccess with the following code but it didn't work. BeTheme support has been less than helpful and takes forever to respond. Hopefully, someone here can point me in the right direction!

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://www.harrisconsociates.com/"

php_value max_input_vars 5000
```